# Cannot contain self-reference in terraform cloudflare page rule

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-cloudflare

I want to create a pagerule to ensure all the incoming `http` traffic will be converted to `https`

Here is my rule:

```
resource "cloudflare_page_rule" "https-only" {
    zone = "${var.domain}"
    domain = "${var.domain}"
    target = "http://*${self.domain}/*"
    priority = 1

    actions = {
        always_use_https = true
    }
}
```

The target line is based on [the example provided by terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/cloudflare/r/page_rule.html#zone)

[image]

However when I run the terraform file, I get this error

```
Error: resource 'cloudflare_page_rule.https-only' config: cannot contain self-reference self.domain
```

Is the example no longer valid? If so, what is the proper syntax?

Comment: That's never been valid. `self` is used on provisioners only AFAIK so it's odd that it's in the docs like that. Why not just re-use `${var.domain}` again?